# Use server for executing functions on webpages with a python or javascrips script

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, server, web-crawler

So my intend is the following: I want some kind of a server which allows me to have a function running on it which executes specific tasks on webpages. For example, a function (once executed) press a specific button on a specific website.

It's similar to web scraping but my main purpose is not to get data (like crawlers would do) but 'manipulating' a website. A simple example: The function on the server is triggered so it accesses the given website and presses a specific button by looking for its HTML-ID.

Also, there are some tutorials on how to execute this with a python script on your PC. A browser window then pops up and the script does what its told to do.

But how can I make this on a **server** where I can't/don't have a browser and where **many requests** from different PCs go in(which would mean that thousands of browser-tabs would open up which is not an option). Any idea how I can make this? Haven't found anything similar yet. Also are there any services for it?

Comment: A server cannot manipulate a displayed webpage.  It can alter a response that it gives, but it cannot directly manipulate the displayed webpage a client is viewing.  The client and the server are different machines, and the server has no direct access to the client's browser.  For the server to make things happen on the client, the client would need to react to results from a server, or in the case of web sockets react to events, and then make things happen.

Comment: no I think you got it wrong. The user does something on his PC (pressing a button f.e.) than the PC normaly connect to the server and execute that function. This function is written i python or javascript and will do than the following: It opens a link (f.e. www.google.com), access the search field, types in 'dog' and 'trigger' the search button. I have done this a lot of times with **selenium** on my own PC. But how can I execute the same function on a server?

Comment: Selenium runs in a browser, on the client.  Nothing about selenium is server side.  Unless there are specific runners that allow it to be ran server side that I am not aware of.

Comment: yeah exactly. so how can I do the same as selenium without a browser windows that opens and on a server

Comment: The server would need to access its own browsers to be able to do that, or it would need access to some library/program that acts as a headless browser, in order to interact with it and do what you are wanting.  But at that point the client and the server are the same machine.

Comment: is there any service offering that? F.e. for web-scraping there is this: https://proxycrawl.com/scraping-api-avoid-captchas-blocks. Is there one for my purposes too?

Comment: Unfortunately seeking references for services and resources is not on topic for Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: ok i see. and I know that getting data happens with web-scraping. What do you call what I want to achieve? Maybe I can continue my search with that

Comment: You are essentially wanting to use some implementation of a headless browser in order to automate some logic entirely server side, is what I am gathering from the discussion.